# Pygame error(Won't import)

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I get an error with pygame when I type

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ImGone\Desktop\pygame\resources\pygame.py", line 1, in <module>
     import pygame, sys
  File "C:\Users\ImGone\Desktop\pygame\resources\pygame.py", line 2, in <module>
     from pygame.locals import *
ImportError: No module named locals
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: How did you install the `pygame` module?

Comment: What do you mean by "How"?

Comment: Did you install via pip/easy_install or using `python setup.py install` ?

Comment: pygame-1.9.1.win32-py2.7.msi 3.1MB this download
http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml from this site

Comment: Fixed it silly little me saved something as pygame /:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were quite a few errors with python in general, where you named a file as a module.
Python first searches the current directory to find the modules, then the path.

If you name your script as pygame, math, random or any other, you will not be able to import these modules.